# Add authentication to the Rails Admin part of my site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rails-admin

I’m using Rails 4.2.1 and Devise and `rails_admin` and I’m quite new to Rails.

I have a user model in the project and a login module for the users. But I need to add Rails Admin authentication. I added a new model `Admin` for the purpose. I have already set up basic authentication for the Rails Admin login. But now I need to remove basic authentication and add a login page for Rails Admin. What changes do I have to do?

As for my code, I am currently using this for basic authentication:

```rb
RailsAdmin.config do |config|
  config.authenticate_with do
    authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic('Site Message') do |username, password|
      authenticate_admin username, password
    end
  end
end
```

I have added a method `authenticate_admin` in `application_controller` that I want to use for authentication instead.

Comment: Please add some code snippet, it'll be easier for people to help.

Comment: RailsAdmin.config do |config|
  config.authenticate_with do
        authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic('Site Message') do |username, password|
          authenticate_admin username, password
        end
  end
end

Comment: Now, I am using this for basic authentication. I have added a method authenticate_admin in application_controller for authentication

Answer (score 1):

As you are using devise with rails admin, you can use devise for the authentication.

In your rails_admin.rb add the following code:

```
  config.authenticate_with do
      warden.authenticate! scope: :user
  end
  config.current_user_method(&:current_user)
```